# Perforce Connection Failing for Mondrian Source Code Repository

Tags: perforce, mondrian, p4v

I am attempting to follow http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/developers_guide.php in the download and compilation of the Mondrian source code.

I have installed the P4V client from www.perforce.com/downloads/complete_list on a fresh install of Windows 7 and configured it for:

host: perforce.eigenbase.org

port: 1666

All I seem to be able to get is "TCP Connection to perforce.eigenbase.org:1666 failed. connect: 72.14.190.177:1666: WSAECONNREFUSED"

I did also attempt to "telnet perforce.eigenbase.org 1666" and received the same type of error.

Has the repository moved contrary to the documentation? or am I using the wrong Perforce Client?

Any provable direction would be appreciated.

Comment: That Perforce server does seem to be down (or at least not accessible from the public internet).  I doubt that a telnet port would be open, and even if it were, it'd be on a different port than the Perforce server.

Comment: @mazrick tried to telnet to port 1666 - that should have worked fine if the p4 server was up.

Comment: Thank you. I guess we will just have to call it a loss until they open a server back up. I've had this issue for some time, so I'm sure it's not just a short maintenance outage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that mondrian is now hosted on github, it was migrated from perforce a few months ago. Maybe ping them to update the doco..